# use POST request in pagination.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm using Pagination.js. In normal way

```
dataSource: `/ajax/products`,
locator: 'items',
totalNumber: {{ $count }},
pageSize: 2,
```

I want to use post request. So I tryed use this code

```
dataSource: `/ajax/products`,
type: 'post',
data: {
    'price' => 200
},
```

But it doesn't work. It display error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id". How can I solve my problem?

Comment: place type,data in an ajax property RTM: https://pagination.js.org/docs/index.html#ajax

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dataSource: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/ajax/products',
                    data: { price: 200},
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            }
```

note : pageNumber and pageSize parameters not fetch it into server side by normal way